# How can I make a udev rule using a “sibling” device's serial number (for USB devices with no unique serials)?

Tags: usb, python, udev, usb-device, arduino

I have testing equipment that is made-up of the following:

- a USB Hub connected to the master PC, the hub is embedded in the test jig and is used so that we have only 1 USB cable running from the jig to the PC.
- an Arduino UNO, connected by USB to the Hub
- a measurement instrument (powermeter) connected to the USB hub through USB
- another measurement device (thermometer) connected to the USB hub by USB
- a Python script that runs the testing procedure from the master PC and communicates to Arduino and both instruments.

All this works well with my first jig but I need now to duplicate the testing setup (3 testing jigs on one PC). I want to assign `udev` persistent rules for the devices so the testers later just need to select 1, 2 or 3 depending on which jig they use, so they don't need to fiddle with the port numbers.

Is there a way to do a rule that would basically say:
`assign symlink /dev/powermeter01 to the powermeter that is on the same USB hub as the Arduino with the serial xxxxxxx` ?

For the Arduino, that is easy as there are proper serial numbers in the `udevadm` info, but for the ***powermeter, the serial number is always the same*** and for the ***thermometer, there is simply no serial number*** (thank you cheap suppliers!!!).

***The USB hub also has apparently no serial.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is not an answer to the question but brings me a solution. so here it is.

I fiddle quite a bit with Udev rules, could not get anything better than my Arduino persistently appear on `/dev/arduino01` (will use `/dev/arduino02`, `/dev/arduino03`,... for other jigs)

My testing script is in Python, I just found out that there is a nice library called [pyudev](http://pyudev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) so I decided to have a look at this route.

After just few minutes, I ended up with

```
from pyudev import *
context = Context()
Arduino = Device.from_device_file(context, '/dev/arduino01') 
Hub = Arduino.find_parent("usb","usb_device").find_parent("usb") #first find_parent brings me up to the USB device Arduino, another find_parent brings me to the Hub

Fixture = Enumerator(context)
for dev in Fixture.match_parent(Hub).match_subsystem('tty'):
    if (dev.get('ID_VENDOR_ID')=="10c4" and dev.get('ID_MODEL_ID')=="ea60"): #I got those ID through udevadm.
        powermeter=dev
    if (dev.get('ID_VENDOR_ID')=="067b" and dev.get('ID_MODEL_ID')=="2303"): #I got those ID through udevadm.
        temprecorder=dev

print('Arduino in on ' + str(Arduino.device_node)) #prints : Arduino is on /dev/ttyACM0
print('Powermeter in on ' + str(powermeter.device_node)) #prints : Powermeter is on /dev/ttyUSB1
print('Thermometer in on ' + str(temprecorder.device_node)) #prints : Thermometer is on /dev/ttyUSB0
```

This gives me the USB ports of my 3 devices of the test jig, I can now feed it to my testing routine script.

The more savvy between us will then have seen that my temprecorder is through a pl2303 USB-serial and my powermeter through a CP2102 USB-serial.

Comment: This is the best solution I could find. There are many obstacles if this implemented using udev rules which make this a fast direct way to resolve the issue: racing condition (USB-serial device node may created before arduino node), could be fixed with delayed RUN script. Need much shell to parse the unfriendly sysfs path (up/down) to scan for other hub child nodes looking for arduino serial.

Comment: For the timing, I do not have much worry as the script will be run well after PC is started. I agree on your point for the path parsing. in my case it hapenned to be simple as 3 times the same architecture. but for more complex cases, one could think of a loop to define the "network" structure.

Answer (score 2):

`udev` does not have only serials to match devices, you can use any property available.

So you can use almost any thing different in `udevadm info /dev/...` & `udevadm info -a /dev/...` from both devices with same serials.

If you can share those outputs for each device, I may able to help. From your answer, it seems you already got vendor/model not the same, so that could be used in udev rules.

Comment: this I knew, the problem was I had 2 identical devices, from same manufacturer to differentiate. in case 1, it was 2 USB-RS232 having both same serial number, in the other case, 2 USB-RS485 having no serial number.

Comment: @Memes , Just one point, Does the jig hub have a serial? or they have same issue: no serial or they are identical. Could you share the output of `udevadm info -a ...`

Comment: the jig is what I made by putting together 3 devices : An Arduino connected by USB, a power meter connected through a USB-RS485 adapter, a temperature recorder connected through a USB-RS232 adapter. All 3 devices are connected to a USB hub. Everything is then put in an enclosure with a single USB cable running to the PC. I have 3 of these jigs.

Comment: Now thanks to udev, I can identify the Arduino as they have serial. then, thanks to pyudev, I can crawl back to the host hub, then discriminate which powermeter is coupled with which arduino, same for the temperature recorder or in other words, I can identify the elements of every one of my jigs without having serial on all of them.

Comment: and as I see I did not read properly your question : no, the jig hub have no serial and they are all 3 of them the same (i.e. same idVendor, same idModel)